# for i in range(start,end): RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Tags: python

```
def quicksort(arr):
    quick(arr,0,len(arr)-1)

def quick(arr,start,end):
    if start < end:
        pindex = partition(arr,start,end)
        quick(arr,start,pindex-1)
        quick(arr,pindex-1,end)
        return arr

def partition(arr,start,end):
    pivot = arr[end]
    pindex = start-1
    for i in range(start,end):
        if arr[i] <= pivot:
            pindex = pindex+1
            arr[pindex],arr[i] = arr[i],arr[pindex]
    arr[pindex+1],arr[end] = arr[end],arr[pindex+1]
    return pindex+1
```

Comment: You should describe the problem better by giving a descriptive title and then stating your doubt in the question body.

Comment: The problem with your code is that the line `quick(arr, pindex - 1, end)` will never end because following your code's logic, `pindex - 1` will always be less than `end`, thus the program will continue recurring. P.S. You would also need to add a `return` at the end of `quick()` and `quicksort()` to make the function return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change is in line

```
quick(arr,pindex-1,end) => quick(arr,pindex+1,end)
```

otherwise it will stuck in recursion 
correct code should be

```
def quicksort(arr):
    return quick(arr,0,len(arr)-1)

def quick(arr,start,end):
    if start < end:
        pindex = partition(arr,start,end)
        quick(arr,start,pindex-1)
        quick(arr,pindex+1,end) #quick(arr,pindex-1,end) => quick(arr,pindex+1,end)
        return arr

def partition(arr,start,end):
    pivot = arr[end]
    pindex = start-1
    for i in range(start,end):
        if arr[i] <= pivot:
            pindex = pindex+1
            arr[pindex],arr[i] = arr[i],arr[pindex]
    arr[pindex+1],arr[end] = arr[end],arr[pindex+1]
    return pindex+1
```